# SQL Server - Get count(*) with filter and without filter in same query

Tags: sql-server, join, filter

In the below query, I am trying to get count of all FTE students by Department and for that I have used the filter `U.[IsFullTimeStudent] = 1`.

Within the same resultset, I would also want to get the `TotalCount` of students in the department which means that filter `U.[IsFullTimeStudent] = 1` needs to be removed.

```
SELECT 
    S.[DepartmentId], COUNT(U.[StudentId]) AS TotalFTEStudents
FROM 
    [dbo].User U
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.[Student] S ON U.[UserId] = S.[UserId]
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].Department D ON D.[DepartmentId] = S.[DepartmentID]
WHERE 
    D.[CollegeId] = 3 AND U.[IsFullTimeStudent] = 1
GROUP BY 
    S.[DepartmentId]
```

In short my resultset should return `DepartmentId`, `TotalFTEStudents` and `TotalStudents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT S.DepartmentId,
       COUNT(CASE U.IsFullTimeStudent WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS FullTimeStudents,
       COUNT(U.StudentId) AS TotalFTEStudents
FROM dbo.[User] U --USER is a Reserved Keyword, but this was one of the few objects that wasn't delimit identified. This statement would never have run
                  --Though I suggest fixing the name; don't use Reserved Keywords for object names.
     INNER JOIN dbo.Student S ON U.UserId = S.UserId
     INNER JOIN dbo.Department D ON D.DepartmentId = S.DepartmentID
WHERE D.CollegeId = 3
GROUP BY S.DepartmentId;
```